# Mongodb with nested Arrays

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I looked on the web and didn't find what I wanted.

I want to know if it's possible to insert an array inside another one like

Let's say I want to do this:

```js
db.siteraiz.insert(     
    SiteRaiz:[
        [{Dados:'idSiteRaiz:#ChartSet',
         [{Metas:'metaValor'}],
         [{Robots:'link1:#linkN'}]
         }]
)
```

Comment: Mongo is a "document" based database...this means it basically just takes JSON objects as its input data...so yes...you can definitely nest data with JSON objects.

Comment: example JSON object with arrays: `var object = {"array": yourarray, "array2": yourarray2}`

Comment: http://json.org/example - here is a better example.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to insert an array into another, but you can't use arrays in objects without a key. This syntax is invalid:

```
{
  Dados: 'idSiteRaiz:#ChartSet',
  [
    {Metas:'metaValor'}
  ],
  [
    {Robots:'link1:#linkN'}
  ]
}
```

You can use objects only with key-value pairs:

```
{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: 'value2'
}
```

You can have arrays inside objects, but you still need to use a key for the array:

```
{
  key1: 'value1',
  key2: ['value2', 'value3']
}
```

I don't exactly understand how you want to structure your data, but here are some working examples:

```
db.siteraiz.insert({
  SiteRaiz:[
    {
      Dados: 'idSiteRaiz:#ChartSet'
    }
  ]
})
```

```
db.siteraiz.insert({
  SiteRaiz:[
    [
      {Metas:'metaValor'}
    ],
    [
      {Robots:'link1:#linkN'}
    ]
  ]
})
```

Make sure you are trying to insert a valid JSON object. You can validate your JSON object for example here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: I see, so i must use arrays that way, i thought about that, but didn't know if i could do the way i wanted to, thanks man, i wish i could vote for your answer.

Comment: @user3529913 Edited my answer to make it more clear what the issue is with your example.

Comment: So, it'd be like this

db.siteraiz.insert(
 
 SiteRaiz:[
  Dados:'idSiteRaiz:#ChartSet',  
  [{Metas:'metaValor'}],  
  [{Robots:'link1:#linkN'}
  ]
 ]

})

i wanted to put meta and robots inside siterais, but what you did (the last one) it's what I want, really thanks man.